# Go Database Server API

Tags: database, go

I spent some time looking at Go a few months ago and was certainly sold on all of the design decisions made by the Go team.

My conclusion then was that official support for a SQL database (eg. PgSql, MySql) was needed for me to adopt it and without that it was not feasible to adopt the language.

While it is logical for large corporations to expend time, effort and money on IT experiments, for small companies and individuals it can be a catastrophe because the risk is not spread.

It does not appear feasible to me to use an open-source API that does not have the backing of Google. Perhaps JDBC or ODBC would be a good start.

Eventually however, performance will be critical, and a roadmap warranted. How can I use Go with a Google-supported Sql-Server database API?

What is the future of Go without mission-critical support for an SQL database API, other than for cloud computing?

Answer (score 4):

Current weekly versions of Go have a built-in [sql](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/exp/sql/) package. It it still experimental, but shows the plan for databases in Go. I guess actual database drivers are not supposed to be implemented in the standard library, but should implement [driver interface](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/exp/sql/driver/). There is already [a PostgreSQL driver](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq.go) doing that, which with its examples gives you a better idea of what to expect.

**UPDATE:** [This link](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SQLDrivers) given in the comment below lists four SQL drivers implementing `exp/sql/driver` package. It also includes a link to [design goals](http://weekly.golang.org/src/pkg/exp/sql/doc.txt) of `exp/sql` package.

Comment: There are already at least four drivers for the exp/sql package, see: http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SQLDrivers